# Linux Mint 18 file manager doesn't show all Windows computers

Tags: networking, linux-mint, windows

Linux Mint 18 doesn't show all Windows computers under 'browse network'. How do I tell Thunar (and other desktop network applications) to try the SMB2 protocol?

#### Background

I installed Linux Mint 17 on a laptop, used it awhile, and then allowed Update Manager to upgrade Mint 18. In v17 I was able to browse to Windows computers on the network and access the file shares on several machines. After upgrading to v18 I can only see 1 computer on the network.

During the upgrade I was asked a few times if I wanted to keep my local version of config files or use the package maintainer's. I said to use maintainers. I don't remember which programs these referred to.

In Thunar file manager *Browse Network* shows the machine I can still access "DESKTOP-XXX" and "Windows Network". After opening Windows Network I see two workgroup icons - "HOME" and "WORKGROUP". The computers I can't see anymore belong to HOME while the one I can access is in WORKGROUP.

In Terminal `smbtree` reports same as Thunar:

```
matt@dell-xps ~ $ smbtree
Enter matt's password: 
WORKGROUP
    \\DESKTOP-XXX       
HOME
```

Smbclient -L \server throws an error:

```
matt@dell-xps ~ $ smbclient -L \\server
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter matt's password: 
protocol negotiation failed: ERRDOS:ERRnomem
```

Thanks to @Ping_Squiddy in https://superuser.com/questions/857324/connecting-with-smbclient-to-windows-7-produces-error-protocol-negotiation-fai/ I learn that `-m SMB2` (and/or SMB3) lets me in the door:

```
matt@dell-xps ~ $ smbclient -L \\server -m SMB2
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter matt's password: 
Domain=[SERVER] OS=[] Server=[]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
    C$              Disk      Default share
    ...snip...
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
Domain=[SERVER] OS=[] Server=[]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

How do I tell Thunar (and other desktop network applications) to try the SMB2 protocol?

**Update:**

Perhaps a small step in right direction: from https://askubuntu.com/questions/919967/how-to-tell-gigolo-gvfs-to-use-smbv2-for-windows-shares I learn that *"editing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and adding the following to the [global] section: `client max protocol = SMB3`"* allows `smbclient` to list shares without specifying the protocol level.

However this has the side effect of not showing any Workgroups at all in 'Browser Network', and also in `smbtree`. And, unfortunately `smb:///server/` in Thunar shows zero results too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in Mint 18.2 some samba server [components were left out](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=157&t=252576&p=1358813). Installing samba as per "[Installing Samba Server in Mint 18](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=224391)" got workgroups to show up in Thunar again.Also helpful is "[HowTo: Samba Browsing Problems Checklist](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=88146&start=0)".

Now I can browse the SMB1 workgroup (named 'WORKGROUP' in the Q) and see their list of shares and access the files. I get an error when browsing the SMB2 workgroup ('HOME'), but if I type the full path I see the folders and files and can then use *create shortcut* for later use.

The key part for my system was `sudo apt-get install samba --install-recommends`. I didn't need to do the other part about firewalls.