# Linux Mint 19 Thunar doesn't list samba shares

Tags: linux-mint, samba, xubuntu, thunar, nemo

I am using Linux Mint 19 Xfce 64 bit, and I am connected to a network with a Samba server. But the shares are not listed in Thunar network.

I can list them with `smbtree` but `findsmb` doesn't find the server. I can open the Samba server in Thunar by entering smb://IP_ADDRESS/ and smb://SAMBA_SERVER_NAME/. The problem only arises since I switched from Linux Mint 18 to Linux Mint 19. On Windows the Samba server and it's shares are listed. I'm pretty sure that the server is correctly configured.

First, network in Thunar was empty. I found this post

[Linux Mint 18 file manager doesn't show all Windows computers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395416/linux-mint-18-file-manager-doesnt-show-all-windows-computers)

with `sudo apt-get install samba --install-recommends`. This fixed the network a little bit. Now I can find my own pc in the the network. But the Samba server is still missing.

Since I can access the server it's not so critical but I want to fix it for usability.

Installed packages:

- gvfs
- gvfs-backends
- gvfs-bin
- gvfs-common
- gvfs-daemons
- gvfs-fuse
- gvfs-libs

EDIT:

I started another pc (B) in this network. It runs Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon with Nemo. There I can see following devices:

- samba server
- my pc (A1)
- my pc (A2) with another name
- pc (B)

Also in Windows Network I can see a Workgroup with samba server and my pc (A1).

From my pc in Thunar I only can see my pc (A2) and Windows Network is empty.

I think that A1 is also a samba server on my pc. findsmb finds only this local samba server. smbtree finds the local samba server and the samba server in the network.

EDIT:
I found out some news. It seems to have nothing to do with Thunar or Xfce. I had an Linux Mint 18 Cinnamaon. It listed all samba shares in Network with Nemo. I did a full upgrade to Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. After the upgrade, the entry Network in Nemo didn't list any samba shares. The same I saw on a Xubuntu 17.10. Thunar listed all samba shares. After an full upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04 all samba shares are gone. So I think the file managers use a tool to list all samba share and with the upgrade of the system, the API of this tool changed.

Comment: Check if `gvfs` is installed, I think Thunar needs that to show samba shares

Comment: @ojs Yes, all `gvfs` packages are installed.

Comment: And is the `gvfsd` process running?

Comment: Yes, `gvfsd` is running twice, once with `root` and once with my user.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing / adding your samba settings to

```
client max protocol = NT1
```

As was advised [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=270442)

Comment: This change is if you can't connect to the samba server. I can connect if I enter the url. But the servers are not listed. Also I tried it and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Also the usage of NT1 could open security breaches and disallows the connection to Win10 shares.